# Restrict access to json file generated dynamically to only logged in user

Tags: spring, security, spring-mvc

My Spring MVC web application is generating some json file dynamically when a user logs in to application and click on some link and then placing the file on server path. The application is then reading the file and doing some manipulations to generate a tree like structure. 
Everything looks good till this point.

Now after user logs out, the file still remains there at the server path. Any non logged in user is able to fetch the content and see this file directly on the url say http://www.xyz.com/json/test.json . I would like to restrict this access via some Security mechanism so that the url is accessible and content displayable on browser only for logged in user. Non logged in user should not be able to see or read the content of the file by directly pasting the url on browser. Note : I don't want to delete the file on logout.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may be better to write the file to a folder outside of the web application and serve it back through a dedicated controller. This would give you the ability to control who can access it (the controller would be accessible to logged in users only) and it would have the added benefit of keeping the data external to the webapp. Keeping the data external to the webapp ensures that it won't get overwritten when a new version of the application is deployed.